# Was your fender "stove-in" after your car was hit by that truck?

Tags: idioms, expressions, dialects

Is *stove-in* — smashed inward — an archaic expression?

Is it a regional expression? I was speaking with someone from my hometown (Salem, MA), and he used the word during our conversation. Made me think about regional language quirks.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: This is just the past participle of ['stave *vt.*'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stave#Verb): "To break in the staves of; to break a hole in; to burst. Often with in." It doesn't seem to be regional, just uncommon.

Comment: Not much to go on, but all instances of ["I'll **stove** your {head in}"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+stove+your%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are from the last couple of decades, and sound perfectly "normal" to me. Whereas most instances of ["I'll **stave** your {whatever}"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+stave+your%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are much older (and sound at least dated, if not positively archaic, to me).

Comment: I don't consider *stove in* all that uncommon (maybe that's regional, or maybe just some of the people I talk to). It's the present tense, *stave,* which you hardly ever hear. (And that's why it's turning into a regular verb: *stove*, *stoved*, *have stoved*, as @FumbleFingers says).

Comment: OED says under **stove** *[irreg. pa. pple. of **stave** v.] **Chiefly Naut.** That has been ‘stove in’. Also **stove-in.***

Comment: Although I've *read* variants of *"I'll stave your skull in"* often enough, that's because some of the stuff I read was written many years ago. I think almost nobody in the UK would use that form today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Staves* is also one possible plural of *staff* /stæf/, meaning something to be leant upon — or broken upon the Bridge of Khazad-dûm. :) Curiously, the plural seems to shift its vowel, making it /steɪvz/, whereas there is no change in the *staffs* version, which retains whichever vowel you used in the singular.  I wonder why that might be?  Growing up, I specifically remember Gary Gygax referring to “Rods, Wands, and Staves” in D&D, and he always pronounced it /steɪvz/, never /stævz/. It was one of those “irregular” plurals that marked you as part of that particular in-group.

Comment: **stove–in** *adjective* 1: smashed inward < *a stove-in barrel* — Cicely F. Smith> fr. past part. of *stave in*, v. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stove-in) Neither archaic nor a regionalism, maybe uncommon. Voting to close as GR.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it was "stoved in", but then I'm English

Comment: I'd say that too. Technically speaking, Mark's right that *stove* is past tense of *stave* - but it's not a particularly common word, so it's only to be expected people will force regular conjugation. Here are a couple of instances of [will stove in](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22will+stove+in+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) showing that we're not alone in wanting to create a new regular verb "to stove [in]", and just forget about the possibility of [will stave in](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22will+stave+in+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: This is exactly what happened to *hoist*, which was the past tense of *hoise* when Shakespeare wrote *hoist by his own petard.*

Comment: @Peter Shor: I've been admitting to having been *"hoist by my own petard"* for so long it never occurs to me to "regularise" that one, but you're quite right - many people do use *"hoisted"* there. It's a long slow process, but existing irregular verbs do tend to become regular, new irregular verbs are almost never coined, and existing regular verbs almost never become irregular.

Comment: @FumbleFingers “Irregular” covers a whole lot of ground in Modern English, of which probably only the suppletive verbs counts as wholly irregular and unpredictable. As for new strong verbs, I have heard three possible strong past tenses of *tweet*, and I can’t make up my mind which I like best: *twet, twit, twat*. :) I long ago relented on *shat, dove,* and *snuck*. Lately I’ve had my eye on *split, splat*. :)

Comment: **stove–in** as *adjective* -- no pt. See also my comment at OP.

Answer (score 2):

The OED shows the verb *stave* as having a frequently nautical application, describing the breaching of a vessel’s timbers. It gives the past tense and past participle as *staved*, but records that *stove* was used in nautical contexts in the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries. The derived adjective, *stove (-in)* is a remnant of the earlier verbal form, in support of which the OED has this twentieth century citation: 'A stove-in radiator with rusty water blowing out of it.'

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary of American Regional English lists the past participle of stave, but also lists the usage that I grew up with in West Virginia and Pittsburgh, PA as "to stub (a finger or tow), sprain (a joint of ligament)" especially in PA, OH and WV.  I've not heard it personally in the broader sense.

Answer (score 0):

Via "Willin'", by Lowell George 1971(ish). 
"...I been kicked by the wind, robbed by the sleet 
***Had my head stoved in***, but I'm still on my feet and I'm still... willin'"
A beat down resulted in the "stoved in head". Clearly illustrated...

Comment: Is this the very first usage?

Answer (score -1):

*Stave* means to break the staves of - a [stave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stave) (etymologically related to "staff") being a strip of wood used as structural element, most commonly in a barrel (which consists of staves and metal hoops) or a boat (the hull of which consists of staves and [strakes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strake)).

"Stove" is the simple past tense of "stave".  Unrelated to the heating apparatus.  There is no "stoved" (unless you mean "cooked on a stove" I suppose).  The past participle is "staved".

Comment: Stove is also a past particple of stave.

Comment: @MarkBeadles -- I can't disprove that, but I've never seen it.  Do you have an example (i.e. a published work that used it as the p.p., and not in eye-dialect quote)?

Comment: @Malvolio Trivially granted via OED citations: §1819 Byron *Juan* ɪɪ. xlviii, ― The other boats, the yawl and pinnace, had Been stove in the beginning of the gale. §1743 Bulkeley & Cummins *Voy. S. Seas* 147 ― Otherwise she must have stove to pieces, the Ground being very foul. §1822 A. Clarke in *Life* x. (1834) 253, ― I found two of the maids··pushing··against the shutters, as the windows themselves had been stove in by the tempest. §1837 *Knickerbocker Mag.* Nov. X. 408 (Thornton *Amer. Gloss.*), ― [He had] stove two of his front teeth down his throat.